# How to equate Meta and Super keys?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, kde

I installed CopyQ program, it's from KDE. I want to make a keyboard shortcut with Winkey. KDE thinks Winkey is called Meta. But my Ubuntu is with Unity, and Unity thinks Winkey is called Super. Because of this, the combination does not work: Ubuntu sends the command to the program that Super + v is pressed, the program says "I have no idea what "Super" is, I will assume that you pressed only v". I tried to manually set the Super + V combination in the program config, it does not work.

How to make in Ubuntu settings that Super and Meta are the same?

Ubuntu version 20.04.6 LTS.

Comment: In the default Ubuntu Gnome dsektop, Super+V is already assigned. So check first if that combination is not also assigned already in the Unity desktop. Either unassign the existing binding or use another keyboard combination.

Comment: I canceled that assign, so that's not the issue.